# What the code for this symbol in latex?

Tags: symbols

What is the latex code for the symbol[image]?

Comment: Several good methods for identifying a math symbol are suggested here: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `\mathcal{G}` 
see also more letters here https://www.dafont.com/forum/read/9009/latex-mathcal

Answer (score 1):

Here https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html, you can detexify any handwritten symbols.

[image]